# How to set superscript footnote mark in the text body but normalsized in the foot?

Tags: formatting, footnotes, indentation

I want the footnote mark to be superscripted in the text body (e.g. Footnote mark²), but normalsize in the foot, to be shown like:

```
________________
2. Some footnote text
```

Also, it would be nice if the mark appeared hanging in the left margin, like

```
   ________________
2. Some footnote text
```

(That is recommended by Bringhurst in his *Elements of Typographic Style*)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `scrextend` package (part of `KOMA-script`) to customize footnotes. See section 3.14 of the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) of `KOMA-script` for details about the `\deffootnote` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote{0em}{1.6em}{\thefootnotemark.\enskip}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Number (*footnotemark*) is out of left margin and that doesn't like  to me, is it possible fix it?

Comment: I'd like to concur with @skpblack. Here the footnote marker in the footnote is set outside of the body text area. How can it be put at the margin instead of in the margin?

Comment: The particular values may vary with your setup, but I was able to align the markers with the body text by setting \deffootnote[1.25em]{1.25em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark.\enskip}

Answer (score 11):

I already had a solution for this problem, which I managed to come up by trial and error... I just didn't know if it was the best way to do it:

```
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \hspace*{-2em}
  \parindent 0em
  \noindent
  \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss %  There's the option of putting \hss before
  \@thefnmark. }%       or after \@thefnmark, aligning the footnote
  #1}%                  marks to the right or to the left, respectively
\makeatother
```

I tried to look at the definition of `\deffootnote` in `scrextend.sty`, but it seems to be much more  complicated than that...

Anyway, the solution proposed by @lockstep is much simpler than this, although this one might be useful for class authors. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

This is a TeX approach, with doesn't need a package. I use it always. Maybe the code can be improved:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\fnBreite}
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\fnBreite}{\footnotesize\@thefnmark.i}
  \protect\footnotesize\upshape%
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\columnwidth}\addtolength{\@tempdima}{-\fnBreite}%
  \makebox[\fnBreite][l]{\@thefnmark.\phantom{}}%
  \parbox[t]{\@tempdima}{\everypar{\hspace*{1em}}\hspace*{-1em}\upshape#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works very nicely, with one problem: very long footnotes no longer break across pages, even when `\footins` is set manually to values small enough that footnotes should be forced to break. The fatal features seems to be the use of `\parbox`. Any thoughts on how to repair this feature?

Comment: @PeterBreitfeld, The effect is very beautiful! You save me several days to fix the annoying issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I found that using the [`scrextend`](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrextend) package for customizing footnotes can introduce issues (such as the suppression of the footnote marker when including a footnote in a section heading). Hence, here’s a solution that does not rely on [`scrextend`](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrextend):

In order to prevent the footnote marker from being superscripted in the footnote text, you can use the following. I did not find this code to create any problems regarding splitting very long footnotes over multiple pages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\templength}
\newlength{\textparindent}
\setlength{\textparindent}{\parindent}
\makeatletter
\let \@makefntextorig \@makefntext
    % Saving the original definition so we can reuse it if necessary.
\newcommand{\@makefntextcustom}[1]{%
    \parindent 2\textparindent%
    \hspace{-\textparindent}%
    \settowidth{\templength}{0}%
    \ifnum\value{footnote}<10 \hspace{\templength}\else\fi%
    \thefootnote.\enskip #1%
}
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{\@makefntextcustom{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~\emph{long} test footnote. A~\emph{long} test footnote. A~\emph{long} test footnote. A~\emph{long} test footnote. A~\emph{long} test footnote. A~\emph{long} test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~\emph{very long} test footnote including two paragraphs. A~\emph{very long} test footnote including two paragraphs. A~\emph{very long} test footnote including two paragraphs. A~\emph{very long} test footnote including two paragraphs. A~\emph{very long} test footnote including two paragraphs.\par A~\emph{very long} test footnote including two paragraphs. A~\emph{very long} test footnote including two paragraphs. A~\emph{very long} test footnote including two paragraphs.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}

\end{document}
```

[image: No superscript for footnote marker in the footnote text]

In order to move the footnote marker into the margin (Bringhurst-style), here’s a variant of the above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\templength}
\newlength{\textparindent}
\setlength{\textparindent}{\parindent}
\makeatletter
\let \@makefntextorig \@makefntext
    % Saving the original definition so we can reuse it if necessary.
\newcommand{\@makefntextcustom}[1]{%
    \parindent \textparindent%
    \hspace{-\textparindent}\hspace{-100pt}\makebox[100pt][r]{\thefootnote.\enskip}%
    #1%
}
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{\@makefntextcustom{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~\emph{long} test footnote. A~\emph{long} test footnote. A~\emph{long} test footnote. A~\emph{long} test footnote. A~\emph{long} test footnote. A~\emph{long} test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~\emph{very long} test footnote including two paragraphs. A~\emph{very long} test footnote including two paragraphs. A~\emph{very long} test footnote including two paragraphs. A~\emph{very long} test footnote including two paragraphs. A~\emph{very long} test footnote including two paragraphs.\par A~\emph{very long} test footnote including two paragraphs. A~\emph{very long} test footnote including two paragraphs. A~\emph{very long} test footnote including two paragraphs.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
Some text.\footnote{A~test footnote.}\par
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{\@makefntextorig{#1}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
Some text.\footnote{A~footnote after switching back to the original definition.}

\end{document}
```

[image]