# Align a footnote with leftmost border of centered text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes

I would like 1. The main text to be centered (unlike CCC...) 2. The footnote text to be just below (unlike AAA... & CCC...) 3. The main and footnote text to have their leftmost border aligned (like CCC..., but unlike the other two). There is a related post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40976/align-footnote-mark-with-text-margin), but it seems to rely on manually tuning parameters.

PS: I have to do the enumeration inline as otherwise conflicts with code.

```
\documentclass[trimmed=true]{bookcover}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{keyfloat}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
% LAST
\usepackage{hyperref}


\NewDocumentCommand{\bookfnmark}{m}{{\color{red}\textsuperscript{#1}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bookfntext}{mmm}
{

  \begin{minipage}{#3 \textwidth}
    \hrule
    % \vspace*{\fill}
    {
      \scriptsize
      {\color{red}\textsuperscript{#1}}{#2}
    }
  \end{minipage}

}


\begin{document}
\begin{bookcover}

  % \bookcovercomponent{center}{above front}{\color{blue}Remark above front} % You won't see it if [trimmed=true]

  \bookcovercomponent{normal}{front}
  {

    \vspace*{\fill}

    \begin{center}AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\bookfnmark{a}\end{center}
    \bookfntext{a}{aaaaaaaaaa}{0.4}    

    \vspace*{\fill}

    \begin{center}BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB\bookfnmark{b}
      \bookfntext{b}{bbbbbbbbbb}{0.4}    
    \end{center}

    \vspace*{\fill}

      \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\bookfnmark{c}
        \bookfntext{c}{cccccccccc}{0.4}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}

    \vspace*{\fill}

  }


\end{bookcover}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output A]

[image: Output B]

[image: Output C]

Comment: Is there a need to use `\footnote`? For example, then only necessity for using `\footnote` would be if you're using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), which you're not. So, technically, you could fake the presentation to resemble a footnote when it's not.

Comment: It's already faking a footnote.

Comment: For future reference: There's no need for packages like `tabularx`, `wrapfig`, `comment`, `csquotes`, `glossaries` and the like... remove everything that is not necessary in order to provide a *minimal* working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option were you fake the footnote:

[image]

```
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ @{} l @{} }
  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\textcolor{red}{\textsuperscript{a}} \\
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[.6\normalbaselineskip]{50pt}{.4pt}}%
  \scriptsize\textcolor{red}{\textsuperscript{a}}%
  aaaaaaaaaa
\end{tabular}
```

You can play around with the lengths of the `\rule[<raise>]{<length>}{<width>}` to suit your needs. It's raised into position within the `tabular`.