# Footnotes with no superscript but indent

Tags: indentation, footnotes, superscripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set superscript footnote mark in the text body but normalsized in the foot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19844/how-to-set-superscript-footnote-mark-in-the-text-body-but-normalsized-in-the-foo)

I cannot find a way to have footnotes with no superscript number in the footnotes, but superscript in the text and with an indent. If I use a macro like

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{% 
    \parindent 1em% 
    \@thefnmark.~#1$\qquad$}
\makeatother
```

or

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]
    {%
    \makebox[9,5pt][r]{\@thefnmark\space}#1}
\makeatother
```

I get the result that the numbers are not superscript, but there is no way to have the indent, even if I add something like that to the preamble:

```
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\footnotemargin1.8em
```

If I use this last command and the following macro

```
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\@makefnmark{{{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}.\ }%
\makeatother
```

I get both the indent and the non-superscript number, but then the superscript is absent also in the main text.

(I am using the document class `book`, but could switch to `memoir`, if it would help.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the koma-script classes and set your footnotes with

```
￼￼\deffootnote[mark width]{indent}{parindent}{definition}
```

See p. 77-78 of the [koma-script](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) documentation.

Comment: The question link in my comment above inludes a compilable example using `KOMA-script`.