# Hanging indent of citations in footnotes using koma-script

Tags: lyx, footnotes, citing, koma-script, jurabib

I'm writing a thesis using Lyx, the Koma-script bookclass and jurabib. I'm trying to format the footnotes/citations so that the citations are not indented in 
The trival example below (edit to remove deadspace) shows a standard footnote 1 and a footnote containing a citation using bibtex.

[image: Exampledifference]

Can people give me any suggestions/tips and hints of how I could remove the dead space between the number and start of the bibtex reference?

A solution from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78935/footnotes-with-no-superscript-but-indent) results in an indentation for both tips of footnote

```
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\footnotemargin1.8em
```

Thanks for any help/suggestions

Comment: I don't know of citations and LyX, but, as always, a compilable example would be welcome. That way we can actually compile and reproduce your problem. By the way, KOMA-Script has `\deffootnote` but I don't think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Is there a common place (used by this forum) where I can upload a tex/bib file?

Comment: This is not a “forum”, you can just put your code in the question. Of course, you don't need to upload everything, but the necessary to make your problem appear.

Answer (score 2):

Package `jurabib` is from 2004, all of its features are supported by the modern package `biblatex` which can be used with LyX as well. 
[image: andyScrbookFootnoteIndent]

This output can be achieved with the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footcite{aristotle:physics}

\blindtext\footfullcite{companion}\footnote{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```