# Footnote marker in text should be superscript lining figure, but footnote marker in the footnote should be full size old style figure

Tags: footnotes, fontspec, koma-script, footmisc

My general footnote layout is like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc} % the whole footnote text is indented
    \setlength{\footnotemargin}{.5em} % push the footnote text half an em away from the footnote mark
\begin{document}
\null\vfill % just for this example
Text\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But this is not how most typographic manuals will tell you to style the footnote markers. Based on such manuals, I want to achieve the following:

1. The footnote marker in the text should be superscript lining figures (I'm not sure yet if I want them to be proportional or tabular -- I need to test and see).
2. The footnote marker in the footnote should be full size old style tabular figures followed by a period and a space before the footnote text.

Now, I could achieve `1.` with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc} % the whole footnote text is indented
    \setlength{\footnotemargin}{.5em} % push the footnote text half an em away from the footnote mark
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{EBGaramond}
    \newfontfamily{\myfootnotemarkfont}{EBGaramond}[Numbers = Lining]
\usepackage{realscripts}
    \renewcommand\footnotemarkfont{\myfootnotemarkfont} % Proportional lining numbers for footnote markers
\begin{document}
\null\vfill % just for this example
Text\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

But this won't bring me any closer to goal number `2.`
[image]

I can change the footnote marker in the footnote with the code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19845/9077):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{EBGaramond}
    \newfontfamily{\myfootnotemarkfont}{EBGaramond}[Numbers = Lining]
\usepackage{realscripts}
    \renewcommand\footnotemarkfont{\myfootnotemarkfont} % Proportional lining numbers for footnote markers
\usepackage{scrextend}
    \deffootnote{1em}{0em}{\thefootnotemark.\enskip}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill % just for this example
Text\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

But this will just use the font from the body text, which has proportional rather than tabular old style figures, and I don't understand how to put the footnote marker at the margin other than specifying some arbitrary number like `{1em}` that more or less looks right.

[image]

If there only was a package that would let you modify all these various aspects of the footnote layout ...

Comment: So you want (using EBGaramand) proportional lining figures for the superscripts and monospaced oldstyle figures in the footnotes, you want hanging footnotes with the numbers aligned to the left margin, right?

Comment: @clemens Sounds about right! Plus that the footnote marker in the footnote should be full size.

Comment: Once you load `realscripts`, `\newfontfamily{\myfootnotemarkfont}{EB Garamond}[Numbers=Lining]` and `\renewcommand\footnotemarkfont{\myfootnotemarkfont}` serve no purpose, because `realscripts` uses real superiors, which are already lining in EB Garamond. I suppose it would be possible for a font to offer several sets of superiors (lining and old style proportional, and lining and old style monospaced), but I haven’t seen it. Some fonts have old style (and only old style) superiors; they’re typographically acceptable if the designer has tucked in their ascending and descending parts a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KOMA-Script (in your case via `scrextend`) has just the tools for this. The only thing you need to do is defining suitable fonts:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}
\newfontfamily\EBGaramondLF  {EBGaramond}[Numbers = {Lining}]
% \newfontfamily\EBGaramondTLF {EBGaramond}[Numbers = {Monospaced,Lining}]
% \newfontfamily\EBGaramondOsF {EBGaramond}
\newfontfamily\EBGaramondTOsF{EBGaramond}[Numbers = {Monospaced}]
```

The `\deffootnote` macro allows both for defining hanging footnotes and styling the marks in the footer:

```
\deffootnote[space for mark]{hanging indent}{paragraph indent}{%
   mark definition using \thefootnotemark
}
```

Setting `space for mark` and `hanging indent` to equal values will give hanging footnotes like in your picture. Using `\makebox[space for mark][l]{...}` will align it to the right, i.e., to the margin. In this case – since the \makebox`will lead to a fixed width, we can also leave out the optional argument to`\deffootnote`:

```
\usepackage{scrextend}
\newcommand*\footnotemarkspace{1.5em}
% footnotes in the footer:
\deffootnote{\footnotemarkspace}{1em}{%
  \makebox[\footnotemarkspace][l]{\EBGaramondTOsF\thefootnotemark.}%
}
```

For the marks in the text there's `\deffootnotemark`:

```
\deffootnotemark{mark definition in the text using \thefootnotemark}
```

where we now can use

```
% footnote marks in the text:
\deffootnotemark{\textsuperscript{\EBGaramondLF\thefootnotemark}}
```

EBGaramond has specially designed superior figures. If you want to use them in the text you can say

```
\newfontfamily\EBGaramondSu{EbGaramond}[VerticalPosition=Superior]
```

and change the definition into

```
\deffootnotemark{\EBGaramondSu\thefootnotemark}
```

Putting this all together:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}
\newfontfamily\EBGaramondLF  {EBGaramond}[Numbers = {Lining}]
% \newfontfamily\EBGaramondTLF {EBGaramond}[Numbers = {Monospaced,Lining}]
% \newfontfamily\EBGaramondOsF {EBGaramond}
\newfontfamily\EBGaramondTOsF{EBGaramond}[Numbers = {Monospaced}]

\usepackage{scrextend}
\newcommand*\footnotemarkspace{1.5em}
% footnotes in the footer:
\deffootnote{\footnotemarkspace}{1em}{%
  \makebox[\footnotemarkspace][l]{\EBGaramondTOsF\thefootnotemark.}%
}

% footnote marks in the text:
\deffootnotemark{\textsuperscript{\EBGaramondLF\thefootnotemark}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill % just for this example
\lipsum[4]
123 Text\footnote{\lipsum[2]} Text\footnote{\lipsum[3-4]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Quick comment. If the footnote markers in the text are real superscripts (`\deffootnotemark{\textsuperscript{\EBGaramondLF\thefootnotemark}}`), then why are they so much bigger than the figures that `realscripts` give you (see my example), when `realscripts` also uses `\textsuperscript`?

Comment: Define what *real* means. You said you wanted superscripted lining figures. If you instead want the “real” figures that were designed to be used as superscripts you can say `\newfontfamily\EBGaramondSu{EbGaramond}[VerticalPosition=Superior]` and change the footnotemarks to `\deffootnotemark{\EBGaramondSu\thefootnotemark}`

Comment: I just don't understand why `scrextend` and `realscripts` give different outputs when both use the command `\textsuperscript` to get the footnote markers in the text. EDIT: That said, allowing me to choose between the two with `\textsuperscript{EBGaramondLF{\thefootnotemark}}` and `EBGaramondSu{\thefootnotemark}` makes it very flexible!

Comment: @Sverre `scrextend` and `realscripts` don't have anything to do with each other. `realscripts` *changes* the definition of `\textsuperscript` *not* to use `${}^{...}$` any more. In fact it doesn't superscript any more but uses the already superscripted glyphs from the font. (Those that can be activated through `VerticalPosition=Superior`)