# Cannot change the style of footnotes using Fontspec and Garamond 3LTPro (XeLaTex)

Tags: footnotes, memoir, fontspec, garamond

I’m trying to typeset a book using fontspec and an OpenType font (Garamond3LTPRo, supplied by my publisher), with Memoir. At first, I used LaTex because using the required font seemed optional (it was not). So I switched to XeLaTex and Fontspec, but I can’t seem now to modify in any way the footnotes (neither the footnotemark nor the indentation). The notes should be in a block paragrah, without indentation, and the footnotemark flush left, but not in the margin.
Is it due to the font used ? I’ve reviewed all questions linked to footnotes but didn’t find anything that seem to work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\settrimmedsize{23cm}{16cm}{*}
\setpagecc{23cm}{16cm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{*}{1}
\setulmarginsandblock{3.8cm}{3.7cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\makepagestyle{myheadings}
\makeevenhead{myheadings}{\thepage}{\textsc{titulus}}{} 
\makeoddhead{myheadings}{}{\scshape\rightmark}{\thepage}

\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{1.8em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill} %notes en §, ms avec appel seul, indenté à gauche ds marge

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={Garamond3LTPro-Bold}, 
ItalicFont={Garamond3LTPro-Italic}, BoldItalicFont={Garamond3LTPro-BoldItalic}]{Garamond3LTPro}

\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{greek,spanish,italian,english,german}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
This is a test to add a footnote\footnote{And this is footnote 1.}.
And to add another footnote\footnote{\lipsum[2]}.
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}}n
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The way the footnotes are typeset should have nothing to do with the font you use. Did the footnotes change when you started to use XeLaTeX? By the way: I don't get the output you show, but rather the output you seem to want to have. I don't possess the font, of course, but I doubt that this is the reason.

Comment: Just to make sure: This is how the footnotes in your document look like if I compile the above code using EB Garamond: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYth1.png

Comment: Thanks. The footnotes changes when I started using fontspec and the GaramondPro police. I rechecked : when I compile the code above with Garmon3LTPRO, I don't obtain the same footnote style as you with EB Garamond, but what you can see in the image above (with the right footnotemarkers).

Comment: What happens if you use `fontspec` but another font?

Comment: See \foottextfont on page 242 of the memoir manual.

Comment: @Jasper : You're right, it does work very well with others OpenType fonts, but still not with Garamond3LTPRO.

Comment: @John, thanks for the tip, I've already tried modifying as is indicated in the manual but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the outcome.

Comment: Just for the fun of it, does removing French make any difference? Footmisc should not be needed. But sometimes some language packages mess with things they should not

Comment: Yes, you're right, setting english as the main language removes the problem. And with english as main language and french as a secondary language, the problem reappears.

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested to me to use the footmisc package, and it does work, with additional customizing to change the footnotemarker in the footer (found in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268373/footnote-marker-in-text-should-be-superscript-lining-figure-but-footnote-marker)).

Comment: It is better to post the alteration what you did to meet the requirement, so that it will help someone in future