# Aligning footnote numbering and footnote text

Tags: numbering, footnotes

After compiling the following document the footnote  appears as

[image].

But I would rather like to have a footnote below  (i.e., the footnote numbering and the text of footnote align and to have a `.` after the numbering) :
What are the possible ways to have this behavior?

1. Hello

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

Hello\footnote{Hello}

\end{document}
```

**edit:** 
 I have applied the solution given by henrique in the link provided in a comment:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
 \hspace*{-2em}%
 \parindent 0em \noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss
 \@thefnmark. }%
 #1}
\makeatother
```

There's the option of putting `\hss` before
or after `\@thefnmark`, aligning the footnote
marks to the right or to the left, respectively. I have just modified the number 
 `\hspace*{-2em}` 
in that code for my particular document.

Comment: one possible approach is suggested here: [How to set superscript footnote mark in the text body but normalsized in the foot?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19844/579)

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton the link you have given actually provides answer to my question. Thank you very much. I think I should remove this question.

Comment: it wasn't clear to me (since your example doesn't mention anything from the `koma` collection) that the answer given there would work directly, so i didn't note it as a probable duplicate.  i think your question has enough different features to warrant its own answer, so it may help future searchers.  so rather than deleting it, if you write a self-answer, i'll be happy to upvote it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have just applied the solution given by henrique in the link you provided:  `\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \hspace*{-2em}
  \parindent 0em
  \noindent
  \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss %  There's the option of putting \hss before
  \@thefnmark. }%       or after \@thefnmark, aligning the footnote
  #1}%                  marks to the right or to the left, respectively
\makeatother`. I have just modified the number  `\hspace*{-2em}` in that code for my particular document. Thank you for interest and link that really helped me.

Comment: i've edited the comment into the question, and am voting to close this as a duplicate.