# Larger footnote numbers with hang option not appearing as superscript in enumerate

Tags: footnotes, koma-script

I have the problem, that my footnote number does not appear as superscript at the word. Instead it appears as normal number directly after the word.
This is part of a template I should use.
However, the problem seems to be with the macro.
 If I uncomment the macro, the footnote appears in the superscript, but is than also smaller at the bottom of the page.
I already searched for a solution, but did not find anything.

So, how do I keep the footnote big at the bottom and also appearing as superscript?
Also this is similar to the other question ([How to set superscript footnote mark in the text body but normalsized in the foot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19844/how-to-set-superscript-footnote-mark-in-the-text-body-but-normalsized-in-the-foo)), I had the specific problem with a macro in my template, which was apparently not correct.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,BCOR=15mm,DIV=15,a4paper,headsepline,headings=small,twoside,openright,fleqn,appendixprefix]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Zeichenkodierung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Trennung von Wörtern mit Umlauten
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[hang,stable]{footmisc} %Große Zahlen in Fußnoten
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}
\makeatother
\let\footnotesize\small
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item\footnote{adfasdf}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Check the documentation of KOMA for `\deffootnote` and `\deffootnotemark`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KOMA has two commands for this purpose: `\deffootnote` and `\deffootnotemark`.  You want to set `\deffootnote`:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,a4paper,headsepline,headings=small]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}

\deffootnote[1.5em]{1.5em}{1em}{%
  \makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark.}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item\footnote{adfasdf}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks good, but it seems to me that the size of the footnote text itself looks smaller than the text "First item".  Am I right or is this just an illusion?

Comment: @ChristophS - The entire footnote (number and text) is typeset in `\footnotesize` (10pt for 12pt class option).  Yes, it is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

One can try this (make change of `\@makefnmark` local)

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,BCOR=15mm,DIV=15,a4paper,headsepline,headings=small,twoside,openright,fleqn,appendixprefix]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Zeichenkodierung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Trennung von Wörtern mit Umlauten
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[hang,stable]{footmisc} %Große Zahlen in Fußnoten

\makeatletter
\let\old@makefntext\@makefntext
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}%
\old@makefntext{#1}}
\makeatother

\let\footnotesize\small
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item\footnote{adfasdf}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```