# Changing the look of the endnotes on the 'Notes' page (\theendnotes)

Tags: formatting, footnotes, endnotes

In the report I am writing, I am using both footnotes and [endnotes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/endnotes?lang=en); footnotes just as normal footnotes, but endnotes for citations (I don't particularly like the normal way of citing things in LaTeX). In order for the reader to differentiate between footnotes and endnotes in text, I have changed `\makeenmark`
so that footnotes look like this<sup>1</sup>, and endnotes, like this<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
\renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\hbox{$^{[\theenmark]}$}}
```

This works well enough, but my problem now is with the appearance in `\theendnotes` section at the back of the report. This is how they appear:

### Notes

<sup>[1]</sup>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<sup>[2]</sup>Mauris pulvinar lacus quis quam ornare venenatis.
<sup>[3]</sup>Nam aliquet augue vel condimentum malesuada.

I would like the **Notes** section to appear like this:

### Notes

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
2. Mauris pulvinar lacus quis quam ornare venenatis.
3. Nam aliquet augue vel condimentum malesuada.

I have tried something along the lines of this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makeentext}[1]{\theenmark.\enskip #1}
\makeatother
```

After the first pass, I receive an error; after the second, nothing. However, it (frustratingly) doesn't seem to change anything! Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how I might go about getting my desired effect?

[UPDATE]

Here is an MWE. I also ran it through ShareLatex, and found that it spat back that `\@makeentext` is undefined - which is strange, because it definitely *is* defined, according to the documentation of the `endnote` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Footnotes
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{fnpct}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote{0em}{1.6em}{\thefootnotemark.\enskip}

% Endnotes
\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\hbox{$^{[\theenmark]}$}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makeentext}[1]{\theenmark.\enskip #1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  It was on a dreary night of November\footnote{Example footnote.}, that I beheld the accomplishment of my toils. With an anxiety that
  almost amounted to agony, I collected the instruments of life around me, that I might infuse a spark of being into the lifeless
  thing that lay at my feet. It was already one in the morning; the rain pattered dismally against the panes, and my candle was nearly
  burnt out, when, by the glimmer of the half-extinguished light, I saw the dull yellow eye of the creature open; it breathed hard,
  and a convulsive motion agitated its limbs.\endnote{An excerpt from \emph{Frankenstein} by Mary Shelley, taken from Project Gutenberg.}

\cleardoublepage

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please submit a complete .tex file as a Minimal (Non-)Working Example (MWE) rather than just the code snippets in question.

Comment: Related: [How to set superscript footnote mark in the text body but normalsized in the foot?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19844) Also, the link you've provided is *not* a minimal document. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for how to construct one, then add it to your question directly.

Comment: Hi @Alan—thanks for the clarification of how to do an MWE! If I still haven't done it right, please tell me. Regarding your link to the other post: that's actually the post I used to get a similar effect on the footnotes – hopefully, there's a way to extend that to endnotes. For now, however, I'm a bit lost.

Comment: @digitalis The example is great now, since it shows all but only the relevant stuff. But we prefer to add the examples to the question rather than as links, since links die (and it's also easier for people to look at what you're doing.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is, unfortunately wrong: the command is `\@endnotetext` and not `\@makeentext`. However, if you want to preserve the layout of the normal footnotes, you should redefine `\enoteformat`:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Footnotes
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{fnpct}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote{0em}{1.6em}{\thefootnotemark.\enskip}

% Endnotes
\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\hbox{$^{[\theenmark]}$}}
\makeatletter
\def\enoteformat{%
  \rightskip\z@ \leftskip\z@ \parindent=1.8em
  \leavevmode{\setbox\z@=\lastbox}\llap{\theenmark.\enskip}%
}
\makeatother

\textheight=5cm % just for the example

\begin{document}

It was on a dreary night of November\footnote{Example footnote.\par With a paragraph break.}, that I 
beheld the accomplishment of my toils. With an anxiety that almost amounted to agony, I collected the 
instruments of life around me, that I might infuse a spark of being into the lifeless thing that lay at 
my feet. It was already one in the morning; the rain pattered dismally against the panes, and my candle 
was nearly burnt out, when, by the glimmer of the half-extinguished light, I saw the dull yellow eye of 
the creature open; it breathed hard, and a convulsive motion agitated its limbs.\endnote{An excerpt 
from \emph{Frankenstein} by Mary Shelley, taken from Project Gutenberg.\par With a paragraph break.}

\cleardoublepage

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]