# How to change footnote number to non-superscript

Tags: footnotes

I've *almost* got my footnotes formatted just the way I want them, thanks to the footmisc package. But using hanging footnotes it's a bit annoying to have the notes marked with that superscript number that rises above the line (probably makes sense to distinguish when the marker is right next to the note text).

I'm trying to figure out how to either (1) have the note marker in the normal footnote text, maybe with a '1.' style or (2) move the marker down so it's not superscripted *above* the line. Any suggestions?

Example code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}        % 10pt footnotes in 11pt doc instead of 9pt

\usepackage[hang,flushmargin,splitrule,multiple]{footmisc}

\setlength{\footnotemargin}{1.5em}      % Between marker and text
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1\baselineskip}       % Between main text and note rule
\setlength{\footnotesep}{\skip\footins}     % Between footnotes [= previous]

\renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparindent}{1.5em}


\doublespacing
\parskip=0pt

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum ...\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. 

Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. }

\end{document}
```

Example output:

[image: Example image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set superscript footnote mark in the text body but normalsized in the foot?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19844/how-to-set-superscript-footnote-mark-in-the-text-body-but-normalsized-in-the-foo)

Comment: Saw that thread. Same basic Q, but the proposed solution messed up all the other formatting I've got set up with footmisc (hanging, etc), or at least I couldn't figure out how to apply it.

Comment: I have retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose that, in the main text you still want a superscripted footnote mark.

Here's a patch to `\@makefntext` which does the trick. I didn't try to check if there are any side effects. Note I slightly changed some of your lengths settings, to suit my personal taste.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small} % 10pt footnotes in 11pt doc instead of 9pt

\usepackage[hang, flushmargin,splitrule,multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter%%
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{%
\ifFN@hangfoot
\bgroup}%
{%
\ifFN@hangfoot
\bgroup\def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\normalfont\@thefnmark.}}}{}{}%
% %%%
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{%
\ifdim\footnotemargin>\z@
\hb@xt@ \footnotemargin{\hss\@makefnmark}}%
{%
\ifdim\footnotemargin>\z@
\hb@xt@ \footnotemargin{\@makefnmark\hss}}{}{}%
\makeatother

\setlength{\footnotemargin}{1.25em} % Between marker and text
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1\baselineskip} % Between main text and note rule
\setlength{\footnotesep}{\skip\footins} % Between footnotes [= previous]

\renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparindent}{1em}

\doublespacing
\parskip=0pt

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum...\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.

Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It will not work if you remove the option `hang`.

Comment: @Sveinung: I never said it was a general solution…

Comment: You did not :-). I scratch my head to get `footmisc` to produce non-hanging footnotes without superscript, lined up at the bottom of the page using `article`. The simplest solution was to change to `scrartcl` from [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script).

Comment: @Sveinung: I've added a second patch which make things work without the `hang` option.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot upvote you two times :-).

Comment: @Sveinung: That's unimportant. I'm perfectly happy with feeling I've been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I think this was what you looked for. No need to use hang as an option.

```
\makeatletter%%
\newcommand\@mymakefnmark{\normalfont\@thefnmark.\hfill}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@mymakefnmark}\RaggedRight#1}

\makeatother
```