# Non-superscript footnotes, in the text

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, superscripts

There are already answers about how to make footnotes marks appear full-size *in the footnote text* (i.e. bottom of page), for example: [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19844/how-to-set-superscript-footnote-mark-in-the-text-body-but-normalsized-in-the-foo), or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306261/how-to-change-footnote-number-to-non-superscript).  I want to know how to make it non-superscript *in the text itself*, e.g.

```
For more information, see [1].

   ----------------
1. More information
```

i.e., *not* `For more information, see^1`

Comment: What about `\cite`, which defaults to setting content in a similar manner?

Comment: @Werner, yeah, that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve, but with hand-crafted citations (i.e. can be normal text), and in footnotes instead of endnotes / a special end-section.

Comment: How do you want the footnote mark at the bottom of the page to be formatted? Typically the formatting for references (footnotes included) match in both the mark and the reference.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. It seems like in text, `[1]` would look/work better than just `1`, so having `[1] More information` in the footnote-text is fine.

Comment: Are you using a special class? Some classes have their own footnote mechanism or fiddle with the basic mechansim.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default document classes format the footnote labels and references via `\@makefnmark`. Redefining it to set it using `[x]` is easily done in the preamble:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% Default:
% \def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\makebox{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

For more information, see~\footnote{More information.} or~\footnote{Some more information.}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I add a space between ```[1]``` and ```More``` in the actual footnote (other than perhaps instead writing ```\footnote{\ More information.}````?

Comment: @ViktorStein: Try [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/riALj3FS) option (prepending every `\footnote` with `~` automatically).