# How can I change footnote superscript size and remove superscript from footnote text?

Tags: beamer

I'm making a beamer presentation and I'm trying to cite a research paper in the frame title with the title of the paper in the footnote. My problem is that the superscript number is big. I want to reduce its size. I also want to have a non-superscript footnote number.

I've googled and found several solutions [here](https://andrewgoldstone.com/blog/2011/10/04/footnote-numbers/), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19844/how-to-set-superscript-footnote-mark-in-the-text-body-but-normalsized-in-the-foo/19845) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333023/non-superscript-footnotes-in-the-text) but although they give me a non-superscript footer they either change the footnote number (in the title) to non-superscript or change the size of the footnote font. I already set the footnote font size to tiny with `\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}` but setting the footnote number to non-superscript removes the font size setting.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
bibencoding=utf8,
citestyle=verbose,
style=ieee
]{biblatex}

% solution 1: changes the font size in the footer
% https://andrewgoldstone.com/blog/2011/10/04/footnote-numbers/
% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{% 
%   \parindent 1em% 
% \@thefnmark.~#1}
% \makeatother

% solution 2: changes the font size in the footer like solution 1
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19844/how-to-set-superscript-footnote-mark-in-the-text-body-but-normalsized-in-the-foo/19845s
% \usepackage{scrextend}
% \deffootnote{0em}{1.6em}{\thefootnotemark.\enskip}

% solution 3: the footnote mark in the title is not longer superscript
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333023/non-superscript-footnotes-in-the-text
% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\makebox{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}}
% \makeatother

\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
  @book{Vapnik:NSL,
    author = {Vapnik, Vladimir N.},
    title = {The Nature of Statistical Learning Theory},
    year = {1995},
    isbn = {0-387-94559-8},
    publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
    address = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Support Vector Machine\footfullcite{Vapnik:NSL}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that shows how the superscript is generated. Do you do it manually or with some bibliography tool such as biblatex or bibtex?

Comment: @samcarter Minimal working example added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first step, you can set the footnote mark size by adding

```
\renewrobustcmd{\mkbibfootnote}{\normalsize\footnotemark\footnotetext}
```

to your preamble. At least this is the starting point if you want to treat citations and regular footnotes differently. On the other hand, if they should match anyway there is the following way.

The footnote mark size is adjusted with

```
\setbeamerfont{footnote mark}{size=\tiny}
```

and the internal footnote text command is redefined

```
\makeatletter
% normal text fn mark
\def\@makefnmarknosuper{\hbox{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote mark}\usebeamerfont*{footnote}\@thefnmark.}}}

\def\@makefntext#1{%
  \def\insertfootnotetext{#1}%
  \def\insertfootnotemark{\@makefnmarknosuper}%
  \usebeamertemplate***{footnote}}
\makeatother
```

The commands are copied from `beamerbaseframecomponents.sty`, therefore this solution is suited for the use with beamer.

Comment: This is great. I don't want to be picky but I tried adding a dot after the footnote number (in the footer) by putting it in different places in your solution but it appears before the footnote number. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: I added the dot in my code. The `\@thefnmark`command at the end of the third line prints the footnote number.