# Change position of footnote number

Tags: footnotes

Thanks to TexStackExchange community, I have learned to insert a footnote after a word. Same as:

[image: fransson]

But when I have `Fransson et al [2]` I want the `2` to be between the 'Fransson' and the *et al.*  How can I do this?

Comment: Putting the 2 between the two parts is just wrong. The name is *Fransson et al.*. Think about if it were spelled out in full. You wouldn't write *Fransson², Smith and Jones*.

Comment: Also, it's very unclear how you are generating the citation callout. Are you using a bibliography package or doing it manually? Please edit your question to include a small compilable document that shows what you are doing.

Comment: No I think this is a misunderstanding. Please  see the Sara's code below. It fulfills my need.

Comment: I think you edited my post in a wrong way.

Comment: Sorry about that. We can revert the edit, but the previous version was not understandable at all, I'm afraid. Perhaps you could try to clarify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way from:

[Non-superscript footnotes, in the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333023/non-superscript-footnotes-in-the-text)

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% Default:
% \def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\makebox{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}

 fransson \textit{et al.} ~\footnote{bla bla bla} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I want the explanation about Fransson in the same page of the cite. and below part of the page. References put it at the end of document!!!

Comment: Sorry, I had to update the code because I had a mistake in the previous code where the references appeared in the same page. In this code, the footnote will appear in the page of the cite and the references will appear in a separate page. Check this link it is about footnotes (different types): https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Footnotes

Comment: The command (\footnote) will create a superscript to the chosen word and it will create the footnote in the same page.

Comment: I regret to say: the [1] must be in the front of the et al in the text. In what you wrote [1] is in the front of the footnote and not in the front of the et al in the text

Comment: I edited my code. Check it again. Another method.

Comment: Wonderful!!! Thankxxxxxx so much

Comment: finallyyyy. So, you wanted the second method? Please tell me so I can edit my answer and delete the unwanted code. :) Good luck

Comment: The second answer is completely true