# Different footnote styles

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

I am using `footmisc` package to create different foonote styles as in the example below. When using the `sym` set of symbols I have to use `\normalfont` for the footnote mark, but with `num` footnotes I have to use superscrit footnote marks. For the first I followed [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333024/140456), but the numeric footnotes are not superscript anymore (as expected). Is it possible to get different styles for different sets of `fnsymbols`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\textheight=80pt% for the example

\usepackage[bottom,perpage,symbol*]{footmisc}
\DefineFNsymbols{num}{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10}
\DefineFNsymbols{sym}{\textdagger \textdaggerdbl \textparagraph %
{\textdagger\textdagger} {\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl} %
{\textparagraph\textparagraph}}
\setfnsymbol{sym}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\makebox{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Symbol footnote\footnote{Blha.} numeric footnote{\setfnsymbol{num}\footnote{Foo}}
\end{document}
```

For clarification I mark the footnote marks that should be supercript:

[image]

Comment: Updated the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the currently used footnote style.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\textheight=80pt% for the example

\usepackage[bottom,perpage,symbol*]{footmisc}
\DefineFNsymbols{num}{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10}
\DefineFNsymbols{sym}{\textdagger \textdaggerdbl \textparagraph %
{\textdagger\textdagger} {\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl} %
{\textparagraph\textparagraph}}
\setfnsymbol{sym}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\@makefnmark{%
    \hbox{%
      \ifx\@fnsymbol\FN@fnsymbol@sym
        \expandafter\@firstofone
      \else
        \expandafter\@textsuperscript
      \fi
      {\normalfont\@thefnmark}%
    }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Symbol footnote\footnote{Blha.} numeric footnote{\setfnsymbol{num}\footnote{Foo}}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want. I have to wait 3 hours to give the bounty, so I'll do it in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

change the line

```
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\makebox{{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}
```

into

```
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\makebox{\normalfont\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark}}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bottom,perpage,symbol*]{footmisc}
\DefineFNsymbols{num}{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10}
\DefineFNsymbols{sym}{\textdagger \textdaggerdbl \textparagraph %
{\textdagger\textdagger} {\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl} %
{\textparagraph\textparagraph}}
\setfnsymbol{sym}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\makebox{\textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Symbol footnote\footnote{Blha.} numeric footnote{\setfnsymbol{num}\footnote{Foo}}
\end{document}
```

### Simple way

I think the right way to use `fnsymbols` via `footmisc` package is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
   
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\begin{document}

Symbol footnote\footnote[1]{Blha.} numeric footnote{\footnote[3]{Foo}}.

Symbol footnote\footnote[2]{Blha.} numeric footnote{\footnote[4]{Foo}}.

Use an optional parameter [2] for defining the symbol. 

\end{document}
```

Use an optional parameter `[2]` with `\footnote` command for defining the symbol. Here is the list.

```
1   asterisk        *   2   dagger      †   3   double dagger       ‡
4   section symbol  §   5   paragraph   ¶   6   parallel lines      ‖
7   two asterisks   **  8   two daggers ††  9   two double daggers  ‡‡
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not completely clear. The footnotes with symbols should be in normal text and the footnotes with numbers should be superscripts. I want different styles for different sets of symbols defined by `footmisc`. Your solution as it is has only one style for all the footnotes