# footnote - how to change the length of lines and brackets

Tags: footnotes

can you tell me how can I get shorter line in `\footnote{}` and how can I  get the proper height at bracket?

It should look like at the picture..

The current look of my tex document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno,a4paper,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{(\arabic{footnote})}

\begin{document}
Wykazemy za Abelem \footnote{ N. H. Abel (1802-1829), matematyk norweski.}
\end{document}]
```

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyzfI.jpg) to picture.

[image]

Comment: Is your problem still there?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [scrextend](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrextend) package ([KOMA-Script bun­dle](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)), taken from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19844) question, I can offer you this.

> The [scrextend](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrextend) pack­age makes some fea­tures of the KOMA-Script
>   classes avail­able for other classes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnotemark{(\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark})\enskip}

%% Taken from scrguien.pdf
% \deffootnote[mark width ]{indent }{parindent }{definition }
% \deffootnotemark{definition }
% \thefootnotemark

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\footnote{Text for footnote.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]