# Indentation of footnotes

Tags: footnotes, indentation, quoting, footmisc

my publisher requires me to indent my footnote text by 6mm (not counting the preceding number). Additionally the footnotenumber must not be superscripted.
The partial solution stems from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19844/how-to-set-superscript-footnote-mark-in-the-text-body-but-normalsized-in-the-foo), but I am unable to control the distance between number and text in the footmark. Footnotemargin seems to be a wrong idea.

In short I need:

- Footnote text indented by 6mm, equal to quote/paragraph identation
- Footnote number not superscripted in footnote
- Footnote number aligned with left margin

Help is much appreciated.

[image: Example of the alignment]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{times}
\newcommand{\eightpt}{\fontsize{8.5}{10.2}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\eightpt}

%Quotes need to be indented by 6mm on the left side. preceded and followed by half a blank line.
\usepackage[leftmargin = 6mm, rightmargin = 0mm, vskip = 17pt, indentfirst =false, font = eightpt]{quoting}


%Footnote not superscripted
\makeatletter
\newlength{\fnBreite}
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
    \settowidth{\fnBreite}{\footnotesize\@thefnmark.i}
    \protect\footnotesize\upshape%
    \setlength{\@tempdima}{\columnwidth}\addtolength{\@tempdima}{-\fnBreite}%
    \makebox[\fnBreite][l]{\@thefnmark.\phantom{}}%
    \parbox[t]{\@tempdima}{\everypar{\hspace*{0pt}}\hspace*{0pt}\upshape#1}}
\makeatother

%spacing for footnote
\renewcommand{\footnotemargin}{6mm}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{quoting}
        This is a quote, 6mm identation on the left side.
    \end{quoting}

    \lipsum[1-1]    

    Text with footnote here\footnote{Footnote text with same identation as quotes, the number not superscripted and aligned with left margin.}

    \lipsum[1-1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code replace

```
\settowidth{\fnBreite}{\footnotesize\@thefnmark.i}
```

with

```
\setlength{\fnBreite}{6mm}
```

The first one sets your length `fnBreite` to the width of the usual footnote mark, so you get no gap between the mark and the text of the foot note.

The second one sets your length to 6mm, so that the mark is set left-aligned in a 6mm box, which I think is what you were trying to do.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your help. I accepted this answer as it was very instructive to see what I have missed in reading to source for that piece of code. Nevertheless my deepest thanks also @Kurt whose answer also helped me to remove some clutter from my code. I am very grateful for both of your inputs.

Answer (score 10):

You do not need to use package `footmisc` to get your wished result.

You can simple redefine the footnote with the following code:

```
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \begin{list}{}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{6mm}% 1.5em <==================
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{3pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
    \footnotesize}%
  \item[\@thefnmark\hfil]#1% @makefnmark
  \end{list}%
}
```

Please see that you need to enclose this code in the preamble with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

With the following MWE (see importand code changes marked with `<======`)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage[hang]{footmisc} % <========================================
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{times}
\newcommand{\eightpt}{\fontsize{8.5}{10.2}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\eightpt}

%Quotes need to be indented by 6mm on the left side. preceded and followed by half a blank line.
\usepackage[%
  leftmargin = 6mm, rightmargin = 0mm, 
  vskip = 17pt, indentfirst =false, font = eightpt
]{quoting}

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \begin{list}{}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{6mm}% 1.5em <==================
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{3pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
    \footnotesize}%
  \item[\@thefnmark\hfil]#1% @makefnmark
  \end{list}%
}
\makeatother % <========================================================


\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{quoting}
        This is a quote, 6mm identation on the left side.
    \end{quoting}

    \lipsum[1-1]    

    Text with footnote here\footnote{Footnote 
      text with same identation as quotes, the number not superscripted 
      and aligned with left margin.  Footnote text with same identation 
      as quotes, the number not superscripted and aligned with left 
      margin.}.
    Text with footnote here\footnote{Footnote 
      text with same identation as quotes, the number not superscripted 
      and aligned with left margin.  Footnote text with same identation 
      as quotes, the number not superscripted and aligned with left 
      margin.}.
      
    \lipsum[1-1]    
\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]